# Powershell script outputs weird error in Azure CLI

Tags: azure, powershell

[image: Error Photo]

See my error photo above. I am running my powershell script in the Azure CLI. It outputs these errors and references a profile.ps1 script that I never created. I believe this has something to do with the first lines of code I run in the script. These are:

```
Install-Module AzureAD.Standard.Preview

Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication
Connect-AzureAD

Get-Module "PSCloudShellUtility"
```

Does anyone know why I would be getting these errors and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to the default `"strict"` execution policy in Windows PowerShell, which is set to prevent the execution of untrusted scripts that could impact the Windows client environment. Retrieve the existing policies with the help of `Get-ExecutionPolicy` PowerShell command and set it to `unrestricted` it the policy is undefined.

Note: You can also try clearing the cache in the current user account and execute the script again.
[az cache purge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cache?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cache-purge)

Refer MS Doc for [execution policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3).

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
```

[image]

Use `Set-ExecutionPolicy` policy to set it accordingly.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Saying that, I tried your script in my environment and everything was executing as expected.

```
Install-Module AzureAD.Standard.Preview
Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication
Connect-AzureAD
Get-Module "PSCloudShellUtility"
```

***Output:***

[image]